# Get elements from row (Telerik Test Studio)

Tags: testing, telerik, automated-tests, extract

So I need to get all the values from a bunch of rows using Telerik Test Studio.
I basically recorded a test to go to a certain page on a web app, and I have a row called Session ID with a few randomly generated rows below it and I want to get the values from those rows, to use with code or whatever.
How would I go about doing it?
Here is a picture of what I mean:

[image: http://imgur.com/ol4XRuH]

Comment: Hi Andy - I think you need to give us more detail about exactly what the html structure is which you're trying to automate. Can you post some of the code?

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved in a [coded step](http://www.telerik.com/automated-testing-tools/support/documentation/user-guide/coded_steps.aspx).

Let's say you have a few rows in a html table and you want to get their values. You need to collect all rows in a collection and then just take the value of each member of the collection.

Here is an example:

HTML:

```html
<table id="table">
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>6</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The code of the coded step in C#:

```cs
HtmlTable myTable = ActiveBrowser.Find.ById<HtmlTable>("table"); //Locate the table
IList<HtmlTableRow> myList = myTable.Find.AllByTagName<HtmlTableRow>("tr");//Collect all rows.
foreach (HtmlTableRow rows in myList)
    {
    Log.WriteLine(rows.InnerText.ToString());
    }
```

Here is a [video](http://screencast.com/t/eryBhUWo) demonstration.

Hope I could help.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You use the ID as Table, but how do I find the id of the table? Do I add it to the element list? Because the table has a few different columns and I only want all of the elements in the 1st row, not the others

Comment: Just was told that we can't use your code because yours is using a Html table while ours is a ASP table using gridview. How would I modify what you said to make this work?

Answer (score 2):

You can find the ID or any other attribute in the HTML structure of the application (e.g. in Chrome/IE by pressing F12).

Here is a sample code against [Telerik ASP gridview page](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx). Here I am retrieving the first row and then only the first column:

```cs
HtmlTable myTable = ActiveBrowser.Find.ById<HtmlTable>("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_RadGrid1_ctl00");
IList<HtmlTableRow> myList = myTable.Find.AllByTagName<HtmlTableRow>("tr");
//First row
Log.WriteLine(myList[11].InnerText.ToString()); 
//First column
for (int i = 11; i < myList.Count; i++)
    {
    Log.WriteLine(myList[i].Cells[1].InnerText.ToString());
    }
```

I also recorded another [video](http://screencast.com/t/qLxKtOwmHm) for a demonstration.

Comment: Thanks for going through the effort of making videos for me!
Still having a bit of trouble. I keep getting this error

System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Testing.Get_Data.Get_Data_CodedStep() in c:\Users\Dave\Documents\Test Studio Projects\Testing\Get Data.tstest.cs:line 182

Not sure why though.

Comment: I need to see your code and your app, so I can debug what is happening. Did you try my code against our demo site? 

If it is possible please share your code and app.

Comment: I think I have an idea of what was going wrong. I was trying to access a table inside a different frame. We have an iFrame on the screen and it could only access the outer area. Just trying to figure it out at the moment if I get stuck I will let you know thanks!